# What is the difference between Reputation and Score

Tags: support

I have searched about bronze badge and i have found that at 200 score you will get bronze badge so i am little bit confuse about Score and reputation is these two terms are the same thing or different??

Comment: Score is the net number of votes you get in the tag.. Reputation is the general amount of points you get through upvotes, accepts and bounties

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Help Center [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about. The more reputation you earn, the more privileges you gain and the more tools you'll have access to on the site
>
> ...
>
> The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and useful answers. Votes on these posts cause you to gain (or sometimes lose) reputation.

A Score in general is the number of upvotes on a question/answer minus the number of downvotes. ie. if your question is upvoted 5 times but downvoted twice, your score for that question is 3. If your question is upvoted 3 times but downvoted 5 times, its score is -2.

As shown in the first link I posted, your reputation is linked to question/answer scores as one of the main ways to gain reputation on the site.

---

> I have searched about bronze badge and i have found that at 200 score you will get bronze badge

I believe you are mistaken, [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=bronze) of Bronze Badges doesn't show any that require a score of 200. The closest to that is the [Bronze Tag Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze):

> Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the [tag] tag.

The only badge to mention 200 is the [Mortarboard badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard) which is one of a small number of Badges that do rely on your Reputation:

> Earn at least 200 **reputation** (the daily maximum) in a single day.